# Is there a way that Windows users can use an iChat server?

Tags: windows, ichat

Is it possible for Windows users to connect to an iChat server?  I have many windows users and  a mac os x leopard server.  I can't find anything I can use with iChat on the mac server.  I don't want to buy Microsoft's Live Communication server.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Apple iChat Server site](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/ichat-server.html):

> iChat Server is based on Jabber, the
>   industry-standard IM protocol also
>   known as XMPP. This enables support
>   for Mac computers using iChat, as well
>   as for other Jabber clients running on
>   Windows PCs and iPhone.

Any XMPP compatible client should work.  Examples inlcude [Google Talk](http://google.com/talk), [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im), [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XMPP_client_software).